# What's the difference between Binding Data to the repeater in the mark-up or binding it programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the difference between binding for example a column called ("Name") in both cases ? and is there's any performance difference ?

1- Assigning the data in the mark-up

`<asp:Label ID="Name_Lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' ></asp:Label>`

2- defining a control object for every control inside the repeater ItemTemplate and find it and then assign the data in the column "Name" to it

`e.Item.FindControl("Name_Lbl")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably get the same results but performance may differ. Data-bind expressions (`Eval`) uses reflection under the hood to bind the data while `FindControl` will walk up the control tree to find the necessary control. Reflection does have some performance cost (depending upon how many properties/names you are looking up although once looked up a propery descriptor does get cached). On the other hand, overhead of control tree walk-up will depend upon how deep is the control tree.

IMO, data binding syntax is more elegant and I will prefer that - performance has to be seen in relative terms - how much extra I am spending as compared to total request time and so data binding cost is negligible compared to other activities such as actually fetching the data. Said that there are variations in data-binding that avoids reflection - see http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/09/20/425687.aspx.

Many times, I use a code-behind property that provides strongly typed property for ease of use. For example, when repeater is bound with array/list/enumeration of entity class ProductDetails, in code-behind, I use method such as

```
protected ProductDetails GetProduct(RepeaterItem container)
{
   return (ProductDetails)container.DataItem;
}
```

And in mark-up,

```
<asp:Label ID="Name_Lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# GetProduct(Container).Name %>' ></asp:Label>
```

Not to mention that you get intellisense working on `GetProduct(Container)` as its stringly typed

Comment: You look like you know what you're talking about =)! .. but I'm sorry I got lost on the programmatical I didn't get what the GetProduct method do or where did you define it ( on which layer ? i'm having BussinessObject Layer, BLL, DAL, Presentation Layer ) .. I hope you clarify this a little to me or if you have any more detailed or learning purpose tutorials on that part .. and about the blog post I've read it before but I'll read it one more time to catch up with you ... Thanks for your time =) +1

Comment: @IKashef, I was giving an example - let's say you have page that display list of products using repeater. And say you have a business object (or entity object) called `ProductDetails` that is used to carry product data across layers. So on your page, you will probably invoke some BLL method that returns you the list of `ProductDetails` objects and you have bound this list with the repeater. In such case, I would create `GetProduct` in page code behind to reference the product being bound to each repeater row. This reference will be used in markup (page) to do actual binding.

Comment: Continuing previous comment... so instead of saying `Eval("Name")` (which is actually a shortcut of `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")`), I will use expression `GetProduct(Container).Name`. Here, `GetProduct` actually takes `Container` which is current repeater row and casts its `DataItem` to `ProductDetails` so that we will eliminate reflection involved in Eval method.

Comment: VinayC Thanks for the great answer (Y) .. if you had any posts/articles that discuss this point in details I'd please like to read it to understand your answer in a deeper way

Answer (score 0):

No difference, .NET creates the same ControlTree on the back-end. This article explain whats going on under the hood of ASP.NET during compilation. It is an older article but relevant.

[Compilation and Deployment in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp)

Comment: I'm sorry, a little question! .. I bind my repeater on the Page_Load event of the page not the repeater's DataBinding event and check if it's not a post back, so I could bind the control only when there's data and only when I need to .. will declaring it in the mark-up will affect that ? I mean force bind it or something!